# How to get pytest to not delete successful test directories

Tags: python, pytest

I'm using pytest and it's been great. My tests use the `tmp_path` fixture to hold a bunch of outputs (log files, plots, etc.). I want to keep these so I have a record of what the performance of all tests are, not just pass/fail. That way as I make changes I can see whether things are faster or slower, diff the logs, etc. Currently pytest only keeps the directories for tests that fail. I've been through the documentation and can't find any flags that will convince it to do otherwise.

Here's a sample test:

```
from pathlib import Path


def test_file_to_keep(tmp_path):

    # write some outputs from the test.
    my_file_to_keep = Path(tmp_path) / "my_file.txt"
    with open(my_file_to_keep, 'w') as out_file:
        out_file.writelines("some good output.")
        
    assert my_file_to_keep.exists()
```

I want to be able to look at the tmp_path directory and examine the contents of `my_file.txt`.

Comment: If you want to keep the directory, it's not a temporary directory, at least from the standpoint of `pytest`.

Comment: Do not use tmp_path fixture for files you want to keep. Pass the path a different way. Please provide an example test that uses the tmp_path fixture.

Comment: @Jortega I added an example. I was using `tmp_path` as the easy way to get a consistent temporary directory (although clearly it's more temporary than what I was hoping for).

Comment: Try hardcoding the path to some other folder that you create maybe in your documents folder and see if your files do not get deleted.

Comment: I've done that before and it works. But when you run the tests multiple times you now have to manage creating a new directory each time. `tmp_path` magically handles that for me. I'll look into using something like https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The temporary directories created with `tmp_path` are kept after each test run even if the test passes.

Running your example code, I can go to a terminal and do:

```bash
marco@sol:/tmp/pytest-of-marco/pytest-current/test_file_to_keep0$ cat my_file.txt 
some good output.
```

Please note that the retention policy can be configured with the `tmp_path_retention_count` and `tmp_path_retention_policy` variables, as described in the documentation [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.3.x/how-to/tmp_path.html#the-default-base-temporary-directory).

Also please note that you don't need to create a Path object with `Path(tmp_path)`, as `tmp_path` is a `pathlib.Path` object, as described on the [documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.3.x/how-to/tmp_path.html#the-tmp-path-fixture).

You could even simplify it with:

```py
def test_file_to_keep(tmp_path):

    # write some outputs from the test.
    my_file_to_keep = tmp_path / "my_file.txt"
    my_file_to_keep.write_text("some good output.")

    assert my_file_to_keep.exists()
```